# Disable multiple undos in neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

In neovim, I want to keep the `u` command in normal mode to undo a single item in the buffer, but I want to disable the ability to undo a number of items, e.g. `24u`. Is there a way I can remap this using lua?

```
vim.keymap.set("n", [number then 'u'], "<nop>")
```

Any other solution is also fine.